# Access Multiple I2C Ports on Raspberry Pi CM4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, i2c, wiringpi, compute-module-3

I am working on the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4. I would like to implement the 2 I2C ports for the 2 different types of sensors. (must be accessed within a single application)

I am using the [I2C Library Wiring Pi](http://wiringpi.com/reference/i2c-library/) for example test cases.

Will you please help me to know, How do I am able to open multiple I2C ports in a single application?

Comment: I don't remember any problems with that.  Where is your code?

Comment: @joan I am using the sample example.

Answer (score 0):

I2C sensors have address and in many devices these addresses can be changed. Different types of I2C devices can be on the Same I2C bus. Be sure you are careful with the pull up resistors (required), if more then one resistor be sure the combined resistance is not to low. Note the pull up resistors go to the 3.3V power supply not between SCL and SDA.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I would like to use multiple I2C ports, not multiple slave devices on a single I2C bus. My application requires a dedicated I2C port for the gesture detection module & else sensors must be placed on another I2C port. Will you please help me to know, how can I manage this in a single application so my I2C port will work parallelly.

Comment: I found this, I think it will resolve your problem. https://medium.com/cemac/creating-multiple-i2c-ports-on-a-raspberry-pi-e31ce72a3eb2  Let us know how you make out with this, it explains it much better than i can in the amount of allocated space here.